# How to generate a signature with a launchd plist?

Tags: mac-osx, shell, date, launchd, echo

Is it possible to implement the following shell script completely as a launchd plist to generate a *signature with timestamp* in the StandardErrorPath / StandardErrorPath files?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hi, your FOO.plist was here at $(date)"
```

This one doesn't work:

```
…
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
      <string>echo</string>
      <string>"Hi, your FOO.plist was here at $(date)"</string>
   </array>
…
```

Comment: I feared that – but five nervous guys with huge reputation from stackoverflow told me to post it here. I'm sorry for that. Thanks to LCC anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

launchd does not interpret `$(date)`. A shell does:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>echo Hi, your FOO.plist was here at $(date)</string>
</array>
```